# How can I define a ControlTemplate for my TabControl without breaking automated testing?

Tags: wpf, automated-tests, qtp, ui-automation

**Summary**

In my WPF application, I needed a TabControl with buttons on the left, so I defined a ControlTemplate with the layout I wanted and it worked fine.

However, my tester's automated testing tool can't see any of the content of the tabs, including the currently selected tab.

**Question: How can I keep my TabControl testable by the automated testing tools, while still defining the ControlTemplate?**

---

**Details**

I'm developing a WPF application using WPF 3.5
My tester is using an automated test tool called [QTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_QuickTest_Professional)
He says he can test anything you can see with [UISpy.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms727247.aspx-)

- When I use a straight TabControl with no Template applied, UISpy can see the content of the currently selected tab.
- However, when I use a ContentTemplate to change the layout (code shown below), UISpy can still see the tab headers... but it cannot see the content.

Sample WPF application (Xaml):

```
<Window x:Class="TabControlTest.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Tab Control Test"
        Height="300"
        Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonsOnLeftTabLayout"
                         TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <DockPanel>
                <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                            IsItemsHost="True" />
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding SelectedContent}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <TabControl Template="{StaticResource ButtonsOnLeftTabLayout}">
        <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center">Button 1</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center">Button 2</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

What my search has found so far:

- A bunch of stuff about having to write a custom TabControl with a custom AutomationPeer (e.g. MSFT answer to forum question [UI Automation: accessing control in a ControlTemplate](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/2916a782-f466-425e-b03a-4fda8072e837), blog posting [Custom Controls and UI Automation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrickdanino/archive/2009/11/11/custom-controls-and-ui-automation.aspx)). But my every instinct says that's crazy overkill, "there must be a simpler way!"
- Some suggestions about giving the ContentPresenter a Name, or x:Name, or AutomationProperties.AutomationId -- none of which have any effect

*(After search I finally found answer but it took longer than I thought it should have, and the AutomationPeer early findings were indeed incorrect, so I'm writing this as a SO question and self-answer, in case it helps anyone else in future)*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found answer in a different MSFT response on a different but similar msdn forum question, [TabControl controls are missing for UI Automation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/fa8eb86f-5001-4af6-adb3-ceb0799a0cf3).

To get the UI Automation working for ContentTemplated TabControl, add **Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"** attribute to the ContentPresenter, like this

```
<ContentPresenter Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                  Content="{TemplateBinding SelectedContent}"/>
```

That's all it takes. UISpy can now see the content of the currently selected tab.

Comment: there is an issue with .net 4.0 / 4.5, and this solution is not valid :( (check last post here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/fa8eb86f-5001-4af6-adb3-ceb0799a0cf3/tabcontrol-controls-are-missing-for-ui-automation?forum=wpf) any ideas how to workaround?

Comment: Sorry, long gone since I worked on that project. I would suggest asking a fresh question targeting .net 4.5, much as this question targeted .net 3.5